# Regex: Match all after variable text

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Regex newbie here. I have text which appears like:

```
"Show title 2012 23 10 this is its title"
```

I need a regex to match everything after the date:

```
"this is its title"
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex works with [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) & [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) using *look-around* :

```
Show title 2012 23 10 \Kthis is its title
```

Another notation is :

```
(?<!Show title 2012 23 10)this is its title
```

See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444 (this is Perl, but works with most of modern languages)

If you need something more simpler, you should say what language you are using.

Comment: If you need something more simpler, you should say what language you are using.

Comment: I need it to work on yahoo pipes, the purpose is to match all after the 22nd character.

Answer (score 0):

in python,

```
import re
dateformat = re.compile(r'\d{4} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}')
dateformat.split('Show title 2012 23 10 this is its title')[1].strip()
```

will give you the output.

you can modify the dateformat to a regexp you can expect.

Comment: When I try this at yahoo pipes it always matches the "2012 23 10" part. I guess I just need the equivalent of `"Show title 2012 23 10 this is its title"[22:]` that I can apply to yahoo pipes.